# How to declare a click on a particular tab to be a new event for use with Rules?

Tags: 7, rules

I want to declare a click on a particular quicktab or any other tab as a new event for use in a rule. For example, when the user clicks that specific tab, an e-mail is sent to an admin. How can I make this click trigger a new event?

Answer (score 0):

Possible lead? The [Rules Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_link) module. The JavaScript option may be what you're after.

Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... lets you create links which trigger arbitrary functionality with the help of [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).
>
> **Example use cases**:
>
> - Publish/Unpublish content
> - Subcribe users to current group
> - Mark nodes, comments (as Spam), unpublish it and block the author.
> - Batch functions like, delete all comment for a node
>
> And many more...
>
> **Features**:
>
> - Attach the link to any entities.
> - Show the link only for certain bundles.
> - Narrow the entities on which the link will be shown using the visibility conditions.
> - The links are usually displayed using Views.
> - For entities that can be displayed, the links can be shown on node view.
> - Supports an arbitrary number of additional Rules parameters for passing context via Views.
> - 3 types of links: Javascript, Normal and Confirmation form links.
> - Use individual permissions for each link.
>
> **Usages**:
>
> There are three types of links:
>
> - Javascript - Links that will trigger the rules using Ajax.
> - Token - This are basic links, that will reload the page after calling them.
> - Confirmation link - Show a confirmation form before executing the rule.

Comment: Hi again, i have added the link and set an action to it and also the permissions..i am not getting how to display it on a page...